# Test and Training Set are Not Compatible

Tags: csv, data-mining, weka, test-data, training-data

I have seen various articles about the same issue, Tried a lot of solutions and nothing is working. Kindly advice.

I am getting an error in WEKA:

> "Problem Evaluating Classifier: Test and Training Set are Not
>   Compatible".

I am using

> J48 as my algorithm

This is my Test set:

```
Trainset:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fm0n1vkwc4yj8yn/train.csv

Evalset:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j9jgxnoxr8xjdx/Eval.csv
```

(I am unable to copy and paste due to long code)

I have tried "Batch Filtering" in WEKA (for Traningset) but it still does not work.

> EDIT: I have even converted my `.csv to .arff`  but still the same
>   issue.
>
> EDIT2: I have made sure the headers in both CSV's match. Even
>   then same issue. Please help!

Please advice.

Comment: Hey Rock, your links still point to ".csv" files, and the headers don't match!  Could you put your most current datasets up so we can try to find the error?

Comment: Also, we can't run J48 without more than one training instance

Comment: @Walter Thanks for your reply. It's the same CSV file except i have added a321 in the end and inserted everything in EVAL as "TRUE" (Fake values) just to match the headers. 

Should I pre-process this with something? Why am I getting this error? I think we need to pre-process it before converting it to ARFF right? Please advice how I can proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common error in converting ".csv" files to ".arff" with Weka is when values for nominal attributes appear in a different order or not at all from dataset to dataset.

Your evaluation ".arff" file probably looks like this (skipping irrelevant data):

> @relation Eval
>   @attribute a321 {TRUE}

Your train ".arff" file probably looks like this (skipping irrelevant data):

> @relation train
>   @attribute a321 {FALSE}

**However, both should contain all possible values for that attribute, and in the same order:**

> @attribute a321 {TRUE, FALSE}

You can remedy this by post-processing your ".arff" files in a text editor and changing the header so that your nominal values appear in the same order (and quantity) from file to file.

Comment: our dataset contains numeric values and our final dataset is "TRUE/FALSE". Do we need to use some sort of filters or pre-process our data set? 

And my .arff file contained this

`@attribute a321 {FALSE, TRUE}` in both test and eval.

Comment: Without your ".arff" files, even a small subsample that exhibits the error, it is going to be tough to help much.  Also, what do you mean your final dataset?  Do you mean what you are trying to predict?

Comment: (once we figure out what the problem is it might be easier to suggest some preprocessing method to avoid it)

Comment: Thank you @Walter for your help! We couldn't have got til here without your help. I was able to re-evaluate using Test and training.  We have added some "TRUE" and also "FALSE" values (There were no false values earlier in eval set) and it started working!

Now my question is: How do I get the row id's of class values(TRUE/FALSE) of predicted attributes? I got everything done I just need to get the row ID's now.

Comment: I think we got it. We checked "Output Pedictions" and the id's showed up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***How do I divide a dataset into training and test set?***

You can use the *RemovePercentage* filter (package `weka.filters.unsupervised.instance`).

In the Explorer just do the following:

training set:

- Load the full dataset
- select the RemovePercentage filter in the preprocess panel
- set the correct percentage for the split
- apply the filter
- save the generated data as a new file

test set:

- Load the full dataset (or just use undo to revert the changes to the dataset)
- select the RemovePercentage filter if not yet selected
- set the invertSelection property to true
- apply the filter
- save the generated data as new file